# Pass array from a C++ program to a C# program

Tags: c#, c++, arrays

I want to use code from my C++ program which would pass an array to my C# program, but I only get an error when doing so with the following code:

```
ClassLibrary3.ClassMomClass a2 = new ClassLibrary3.ClassMomClass(pmyarray2, inputArray2.Length, 0, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0);
int* ptr = a2.GetArray();
for (int i = 0; i < inputArray2.Length; i++)
{

     outputArray[i] = *(ptr + i);
}
```

`GetArray()` returns an `int*`.

The values are passed, but I am unable to copy them to `outputArray`.

This is the error I'm receiving:

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting? What do you mean when you say that you can't get the values to `outputArray`? How do you know that the values are passed?

Comment: The control values by performing a loop with Console.WriteLine (ptr [i]), does not give me a real mistake, I stopped the execution of the program and tells me that string of code wrong .the problem is that I can not copy values from ptr [i] to outputArray

Comment: If there is an error, please copy the message as it is shown and edit your question to include it.

Comment: Your `outputArray` is probably too small.

Comment: ty, resolved, I created a new a = array [length] and output to Array =

Answer (score 0):

Your `outputArray` is too small. Create a larger array or alternatively use a [`List<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) if you don't know the array's size.